# Neo4j - shortestPath through node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, shortest-path

I am trying to get the shortest path between node `(a)` and node `(c)` through a particular node `(b)` that has the label `SomeImportantLabel`. Drawn, this is what I want:

```
(a)-(?..)-(b:SomeImportantLabel)-(?..)-(c)
```

Note that `(?..)` means that there might be `'n'` number of nodes in between.

Something like this would be the deal I am looking for:

```
match p = allShortestPaths((a)-[*]-(b:SomeImportantLabel)-[*]-(c)) 
where id(a) = 123 and id(c) = 456 
return nodes(p) as nodes, relationships(p) as rels;
```

Since it is not possible to have multiple relations in a `shortestPath`/`allShortestPaths` function, I have read here on `SO` that you would have to do it this way:

```
match p1 = allShortestPaths((a)-[*]-(b:SomeImportantLabel)), p2=allShortestPaths((b:SomeImportantLabel)-[*]-(b)) 
where id(a) = 123 and id(c) = 456 
return nodes(p1)+nodes(p2) as nodes, relationships(p1)+relationships(p2) as rels;
```

This however gives me way too many nodes that are not even involved and it takes forever to process this query. I think this is because I'm not sure if the same `(b)` node is used in the 2 allShortestPaths functions.
This would be the result more or less:

```
       /-(v2)
      /-(v1)
(a)-(x1)-(b)-(x2)-(c)
 \-(y1)   \-(z1)-(z2)
```

The ideal solution would be something like this:

```
(a)-(x1)-(b1)-(x2)-(c)
 \-(b2)-(y1)-(y2)-(c)
```

This means that there are 2 shortest paths found between `(a)` and `(c)` that go through a node `(b)` with label 'SomeImportantLabel'.

Comment: Is id(b) suppose to be id(c)? Your cyphers has presented don't bind node c to any particular node.

Comment: Also, does b need to be any particular node, or is `MATCH p=allShortestPaths((a)-[*]-(c)) WHERE ANY(n in NODES(p) WHERE a<>n<>c AND n:SomeImportantLable)` semantically equivalent?

Comment: You have multiple typos in your second query. The `allShortestPaths` function calls are missing the ending ")", and `(b:SomeImportantLabel)-[*]-(b)` should probably not have `b` on both ends. Can you fix that query (and also answer @Tezra's first comment, which is very important)?

Comment: @Tezra, @cybersam you are right, it had to be `id(c)` instead of `id(b)`. For b, it doesn't matter which node it is, as long as it has the label `SomeImportantLabel`. It looks like your trick seems to be working with the `ANY(n in NODES(p) where a<>n<>c AND n:SomeImportantLabel`. I'll give it one more test round.

Comment: @Tezra, can you post your suggestion in an answer, so I can mark it being the answer to my question? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ANY/ALL/SINGLE/NONE functions to filter path results in the WHERE part, and Neo4j can apply those filters (at least for ALL/NONE if needed) while searching the path.

So for example...

```
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((a)-[*]-(c))
WHERE ID(a) = 123 AND ID(c) = 456 
AND ANY(b in NODES(p) WHERE a<>b<>c AND b:SomeImportantLabel)  
RETURN nodes(p) as nodes, relationships(p) as rels;
```

Also, while we could truncate the head/tail of the list from the filter set of ANY, the Cypher planner likes for the same filter to apply to the whole path, so it's better to exclude them in the WHERE part.

Comment: The part `ANY(b in NODES(p) where a<>b<>c AND b:SomeImportantLabel)` is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Keep in mind that only all() and none() type predicates are evaluated during expansion. single() and any() are evaluated as filters after all expanded paths are found. That said, I don't believe there's a better approach here.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Thanks. Added the ALL/NONE clarification to the answer. I wasn't sure if the planner had any optimizations for ANY/SINGLE, but that might change in the future